# Mentions up down arrow not working after draftjs custom key binding

Tags: draftjs, mention, draft-js-plugins

When I use "draft-js" custom key binding, the up and down button of its mentions plugin on suggestion popup stopped working.

As per documentation, I have tried to return `getDefaultKeyBinding(event)` in case if my custom condition is not met, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue and its resolution is nicely explained in [Answer](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/blob/master/FAQ.md#keybindings-added-by-a-plugin-stop-working-when-using-custom-keybindingfn-function).

Credits to : draft-js-plugins/FAQ.md